# Common Lisp functions that accept arguments either by position or by keyword?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

**Q:** is it possible to write a Common Lisp function that accepts the same arguments either by position or by keyword?  If so, how?

For example, how could one rewrite the following function:

```
(defun fnx (&key a b c)
  (list a b c))
```

Such that one could legally call it in each of the following ways:

```
(fnx 1 2 3)
(fnx :a 1 :b 2 :c 3)
(fnx 1 2 :c 3)
```

Comment: The semantics are not clear. What is `:a :b`? Is it one argument or two arguments? You can always use a `&rest` argument list and parse it yourself. Generally I would see such flexible argument lists as bad style, since it makes errors more likely. Note also that in Common Lisp the keys don't necessarily need to be keyword symbols. Normal symbols can be used, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, but, no, you don't want to.

More precisely, if you can write the spec, you can implement it in Lisp, but I don't think you can write an unambiguous spec.  E.g., what should these invocations return:

```
(fnx :a :b :c)
(fnx :a :c :b)
(fnx :b :a :a)
(fnx :a :a :a)
```

and many other corner cases.

You can, of course, write something like this:

```
(defun parse-my-args (&rest args)
   (let (a b c (curpos 0))
     ... some hairy processing
     (values a b c)))

(defun fnx (&rest args)
  (multiple-values-bind (a b c) (parse-my-args args)
    ...))
```

and declare that whatever the code is doing is the right thing, but this does not look like a good idea.

I suggest you think what you want to accomplish and ask a question about that.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [sds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25808357/3687048), I would recommend you reading [this chapter](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/functions.html) of '[Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/)'.

Author of the book describes how one can combine different types of function arguments and which combinations should be avoided.

Here is relevant citation:

> The other two combinations, either **&optional** or **&rest** parameters combined with **&key** parameters, can lead to somewhat surprising behavior. <...> You can safely combine **&rest** and **&key** parameters, but the behavior may be a bit surprising initially. Normally the presence of either **&rest** or **&key** in a parameter list causes all the values remaining after the required and **&optional** parameters have been filled in to be processed in a particular way--either gathered into a list for a **&rest** parameter or assigned to the appropriate **&key** parameters based on the keywords. If both **&rest** and **&key** appear in a parameter list, then both things happen--all the remaining values, which include the keywords themselves, are gathered into a list that's bound to the **&rest** parameter, and the appropriate values are also bound to the **&key** parameters.

So using of `&rest` (which is how you can 'index' parameters of a function) excludes possibility of using `&key`.

Of course, one can do any kind of insane mess with such a crazy tool as Lisp, but in this particular case it is not worth it.